# How to call my model or controller of codeigniter outside application directory?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following doubts:

I have my project in codeigniter which uses Flash. Its structure is as follows:

```
name_proyect
      application /
             controller /
             model /
             view /
      audiofiles/
            //Here are being saved all audios.
      user_guide /
      flash /
            archivos.swf
            save_audio.php
      system /
      index.php
```

The flash uses **save_audio.php** file, which is saving an audio on my server.
However, when I save the physical file on my server also need to save the file path in my database associated with the user.

My question is, I can use the active record in the file of codeigniter **save_audio.php**? o I can use my model or controller that use the model in my project that saving to database?

***NOTE:*** `save_audio.php` is a simple script (isn't a class)

Comment: which file you want to use `save_img.php` or `save_audio.php`?

Comment: btw where your audio file saved? you can retrieve it taking reference with `base_url() or `site_url()`. hope it make sense?

Comment: @diEcho my apologize, I was wrong with the file save_img.php. I want to use save_audio.php

Comment: @diEcho the audios files are being saved at the audiofiles. I update the  estructure of my directories

Comment: Why don't you put the code on that file inside a controller? It would be easier

Comment: @oso96_2000 yes, you have the reason. But i don't know how the flash can call a method inside on the controller. Not recognized the function.
This is a reason for create a new file and only call the save_audio.php only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the current content of the `save_audio.php` into a CI controller. If you can, edit the flash file so it sends the files/requests to the new place.

If you can't update the flash file, remove the `save_audio.php` so CI will pick up the request, and use the routes config to make the path routed to your new controller inside CI. In this case you will end up something like this:

**application/controllers/upload.php** - the newly created controller

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {
    public function handle_audiofile() {
        // the original content of the save_audio.php comes here.
        // might need to update some superglobal usage
    }
}
```

**application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['application/flash/save_audio.php'] = 'upload/handle_audiofile';
```